# angularjs - how to evaluate value with internal $interpolated expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-interpolate

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do the following:

I have a 'translation' service to convert keys into a string (for localization). A directive 'local' calls this. It looks like this:

```
<local>key</local>
```

This looks up 'key' in the translation data and returns its value, then replaces itself with the value. so maybe the key 'username' returns the value 'User Name:' for inclusion in a page.

The problem: I want to support strings with "values", e.g. the key 'minLength' has the string value 'The minimum length is {0} characters'. I'd like something like the following:

```
<local>
  <key>minLength</key>
  <val>{{policy.minLength}}</val>
</local>
```

I hit an issue when the value of $scope.policy has not yet been set by the time the `<local>` tag is evaluated (in its link phase).

I assume that since I'm replacing the 'local' tag with a value, the actual tag is not sticking around to be evaluated again when $scope.policy.minLength actually has a value.

Can somebody give me an idea how to do this? I've looked up stuff on $interpolate, but I think the fact the `<local>` tag is replace:true is killing me here. Any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: How about a plunker? and we'll see if we can fix that for you.

Comment: Don't put `$scope` in the Angular expression use `{{policy.minLength}}`.

Comment: Doh! Removed the use of $scope as suggested. And I'll see what I can come up with for a plunker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Using the example above:

- Get the text content of the key and any `<val>` tags.
- Call the translation service to retrieve the format string (for the key) with the `<val>` contents added to it. That value will be "The minimum length is {{policy.minLength}} characters".
- Create a $watch. The 'current value function' part creates an $interpolate() on the value above, then evaluates it in the context of the current scope.
- Replace the original `<local>` tag with a `<span>` (i.e. the equivalent of 'replace:true')
- Whenever the value of the $watch changes, just replace the textContent of the `<span>` with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your directive to **transclude** and also use the built  directive to control the evaluation of the inner statement.

See if this helps:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. At the point I process <local> I can pick up <key> and <val> and their text content. But if I evaluate {{$scope.policy.minLength}} then (using $interpolate), it's empty (""). I'm not sure how transclusion would help. I also tried just putting the text content into the value (so I had "The minimum length is {{$scope.policy.minLength} characters" as the string, but of course that itself doesn't get translated (we're already in the link phase). Can you explain how transclude would help here? (I do understand what it does in general).